# Count number and start with 1 again

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, insert

I am thinking a long time for a solution but I don't find any to fix my problem:

Explanation:
I have the variable x.  x is a ID number between 1 and 99 in my oracle db.

After I fill out the form I insert till max 8 rows in my db (because i have dynamic textboxes and so I insert from 1 row till 8 tows). Now I want to count x till 99 and after it reached 99 it should start at 1 again.

The problem is that I actually insert the following line:

```
Row1: Insert (text, 97) (97 is the ID)
Row2: Insert (text, 98) (98 is the ID)
Row3: Insert (text, 99) (99 is the ID)
Row4: Insert (text, 100) (100 is the ID) now here is the problem, it should begin at 1 again and insert 1.
Row5: Insert (text, 101) (101 is the ID) should be 2.
...
```

I hope that someone knows easily the solution.

Comment: The "start with 1" approach makes it a bit weird, but are you looking for something like `int id = (x % 99) == 0 ? 99 : (x % 99);`?

Comment: or `int id = (x - 1) % 99 + 1;`

Comment: @HansKilian - that's... actually nicer.

Comment: Why you have an ID which max value is 99? That doesn't sound like it should be calculated by the client but in the DB and if you later need a batch size of 100 use [database paging](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-do-pagination-in-oracle-database-sql-query).

Comment: Rango - Its not an DB ID, just an internal ID which is not a primary key or something.
Hans Kilian - How i have to insert that in a code for 8 variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take the remainder of a division, you can use the modulus operator `%`. But that works best on sequences that start with 0. So if you map your ´x´ from 1-99 to 0-98 by subtracting 1, you can take the modulus and take the remainder of a division by 99. Then you can map it back to 1-99 by adding 1 again.
So the statement becomes

```
int id = (x - 1) % 99 + 1;
```

Edit: Not quite sure what you mean in your question. But if you take a value of x of 102, then the id becomes 3. It does that by first subtracting 1, so it's 101. Then it takes the remainder when divided by 99. That's 2. And then it adds 1 again, so it becomes 3. So the id that corresponds to an x value of 102 is 3.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Now i have 8 variables:
ID1
ID2
ID3
ID4
ID4
ID5
ID6
ID7
ID8

i use them for 8 inserts.

With a button click i read the last ID from the DB.
So i have the variable x from the db.

how i count now the 8 variables up and if e.g. variable 6 is 99 how i can make that variable 7 start from 1?

Comment: @Tobias (x + i - 1) % 99 + 1? Where i is the 0 based index of you variables. E.g. (x + 7 - 1) % 99 + 1 for ID8

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. im a amateur in programming but i give my best.
Is it possible to get an example for this? 
I declared this variables:

 int x = valueIDfromDB; (valueIDfromDB is 96)

            int id1;
            int id2;
            int id3;
            int id4;
            int id5;
            int id6;
            int id7;
            int id8;


commandtext=" insert into XX values(text, id1);
commandtext=" insert into XX values(text, id2);
commandtext=" insert into XX values(text, id3);
commandtext=" insert into XX values(text, id4);
...